# Can't get gulp-rev-replace working with gulp-useref

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-rev

Continuing my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615542/css-and-js-minification-doesnt-work-with-gulp-filter-gulp-csso-gulp-uglify) - but this time is the next step: getting file revisions to work.

I'm working through johnpapa's course on automation with Gulp and seem to hit another wall (that's what you get when you try to adapt a concise course to a different file structure :P ).

Basically, the issue is that I do get files named with a revision, but those names do not get into the end-result `test.jsp`, and I can't figure out why...

This is the task (the minification is omitted for brevity, but it works fine with the file revisioning):

```
gulp.task('build-dev', ['inject'], function () {

    var assets = $.useref.assets({searchPath: ''});

    return gulp
        .src(config.indexFile)
        .pipe($.rename('test.jsp'))
        .pipe($.plumber())
        .pipe(assets)
        .pipe($.rev())
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe($.useref())
        .pipe($.revReplace({modifyUnreved: replaceDirectory, modifyReved: replaceDirectory}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.indexLocation))
        .pipe($.rev.manifest())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.indexLocation))
        ;
});
```

`inject` is the task that injects css and js references to the index file (works correctly), `$` is `require('gulp-load-plugins')({lazy: true})` and `config.indexFile` is `index.jsp`.

The `replaceDirectory` function is (used since the rev-manifest generates full pathnames):

```
function replaceDirectory(path) {

    var strToReplace = '../..';
    var strToReplaceWith = process.cwd().replace(/\\/g, '/') + '/WebContent';

    if (path) {
        return path.replace(strToReplace, strToReplaceWith);
    } else {
        return path;
    }
}
```

My file structure (unlike the one in the course) is:

```
- ModuleDir
    - dist
        - css
            - lib.css
            - app.css
        - fonts
        - images
        - js
            - lib.js
            - app.js
    - css
    - js
    - web-app
        - InnerDir
            - index.jsp
            - test.jsp
    - package.json, bower.json, etc. (all the required files)
```

Basically, index.jsp is processed for CSS and JS library and application assets, which are minified and concatenated into lib.css, lib.js, app.css and app.js. Later all these are injected into a copy of index.jsp which is called test.jsp.

The asset gathering, concatenation, injection works and file revisions on disk work splendidly. The update of file names in `test.jsp`- not so much...

Any ideas or pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add `replaceInExtensions: '.jsp'` to your options for `revReplace()`.

I had this problem for a day and a half before I looked at the plugin code and figured it out. I'm using .php files. The documentation does say you need to do this but it's easily missed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will check this later, but it does make sense - and I did miss it in the docs... :) Will stick with my solution (it fits our dev process better, in the end), but nice to know the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime (unless I find the source of the problem or any of you can help), I've chosen a different cache busting scheme:

```
gulp.task('build-dev', ['inject'], function () {

    var assets = $.useref.assets({searchPath: ''});
    var cb = Math.random();

    return gulp
        .src(config.indexFile)
        .pipe($.rename('test.jsp'))
        .pipe($.plumber())
        .pipe(assets)
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe($.useref())
        .pipe($.replace('dist/css/lib.css', 'dist/css/lib.css?cb=' + cb))
        .pipe($.replace('dist/css/app.css', 'dist/css/app.css?cb=' + cb))
        .pipe($.replace('dist/js/lib.js', 'dist/js/lib.css?cb=' + cb))
        .pipe($.replace('dist/js/app.js', 'dist/js/app.js?cb=' + cb))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.indexLocation))
        ;
});
```

It's not the answer I want, but it is an answer I need. :)